# What are the advantages of adding delegate instances to Component.Events (EventHandlerList)?

Tags: c#, winforms

In class's derived from a Component I sometimes see events declared like:

```
private static readonly object LoadEvent = new object();
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> Load
{
    add { Events.AddHandler(LoadEvent, value); }
    remove { Events.RemoveHandler(LoadEvent, value); }
}

protected virtual void OnLoad(MyEventArg e)
{
    var evnt = (EventHandler<MyEventArg>)Events[LoadEvent];
    if (evnt != null) 
        evnt(this, e);
}
```

Instead of just:

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> Load;

protected virtual void OnLoad(MyEvent e)
{
   if (Load != null)
       Load(this, e);
}
```

I'm tempted to to refactor to use the shorter method, but I am hesitant in case there are some advantages to using the Component EventHanderList that I am missing.

The only advantages I can currently think of are:

- When the component is disposed, all items in the EventHandlerList are removed, effectively automatically unhooking event handlers.
- Possibly less memory fragmentation because of all the attached delegates going into the single EventHandlerList.

Is there anything else?

(This is **not** a question about the general use of explicit add + removes on events.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is good for **sparse** events. UI controls tend to have dozens (sometimes upwards of 100) events. If a field-like-event was used for each, then **each event** requires a reference backing-field. With 100 events, that is 400 bytes on x86 or 800 bytes on x64, ***even if not a single event is subscribed***.

As an example, a winforms `System.Windows.Forms.Form` has 91 events **before you've added any**. Every single `Control` instance has *at least* 69.

So; a windows form with a few labels, input boxes and buttons could easily have an extra 2000 reference fields (16k on x86) *most of which are doing nothing*.

The `EventHandlerList` is essentially a key/value lookup, which means that if only 3 events are subscribed (I'm thinking "Click" and maybe a few others) then only a nominal amount of memory is required.

Comment: If it's only about backing fields performance improvement. This sounds more like a compiler job that a syntax sugar should do when the event properties in a class are more than 1.